# What in FreeRTOS's xStreamBufferSendFromISR() makes it "ISR safe"?

Tags: freertos

The FreeRTOS docs:
https://www.freertos.org/xStreamBufferSendFromISR.html
has the generic NOTE which says the function is safe for use in an ISR but it doesn't explain *why*.
What is in this function that's not in xStreamBufferSend() which makes it ISR safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the Chapter 6 of the [FreeRTOS book](https://www.freertos.org/fr-content-src/uploads/2018/07/161204_Mastering_the_FreeRTOS_Real_Time_Kernel-A_Hands-On_Tutorial_Guide.pdf):

> **The Interrupt Safe API**
>
> Often it is necessary to use the functionality provided by a FreeRTOS
> API function from an interrupt service routine (ISR), but many
> FreeRTOS API functions perform actions that are not valid inside an
> ISR—the most notable of which is placing the task that called the API
> function into the Blocked state; if an API function is called from an
> ISR, then it is not being called from a task, so there is no calling
> task that can be placed into the Blocked state. FreeRTOS solves this
> problem by providing two versions of some API functions; one version
> for use from tasks, and one version for use from ISRs. Functions
> intended for use from ISRs have “FromISR” appended to their name.